# Spring controller @ResponseBody does not return exptected value

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring controller class which returns JSON having @ResponseBody. But strangely, it returns integer for double field. I am using JacksonMapper as JSON library. Here are the classes.

```
Phone
public class Phone implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty(value="phoneid")
    private long phoneId;

    private Plan plan;
    private String sim;
    private String imei;

    @JsonProperty(value="phonetype")
    private String phoneType;

    @JsonProperty(value="phonenumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String label;
    @JsonProperty(value="connecteddate")
    private String connectedDate;
        //getters and setters
} 

Plan
public class Plan implements Serializable {
        @JsonProperty(value="planid")
    private long planId;

    @JsonProperty(value="planname")
    private String planName;

    private double billingIncrement;

    private double owiStdUnitCost;

    private double owiFlagFall;

    private double stdCap;

    private double dataCap;

    private double smsCap;

    private double owiDataUnitCost;

    private double owiSms;
        //getters and setters
}

PhoneResult
public class PhoneResult implements Serializable {
private boolean ok;
    private String message;
    private Phone result;

//getters and setters
}
```

When I return PhoneResult oject, it returns like this:

```
{
   "ok": true,
   "message": "",
   "result":
   {
       "phoneid": 600003,
       "phonenumber": "12343423",
       "phonetype": "Samsung Galaxy S2",
       "imei": "343242",
       "sim": "1234324",
       "label": "Mr Bean",
       "connecteddate": "2012-09-19 00:00:00.0",
       "plan":
       {
           "planid": 34,
           "planname": "$59 Jeenee Plan",
           "billingIncrement": 30,
           "owiStdUnitCost": 81.8181818181818,
           "owiFlagFall": 0,
           "stdCap": 636.3636,
           "dataCap": 227.2665,
           "smsCap": 1363.638,
           "owiDataUnitCost": 0.022194,
           "owiSms": 22.7272727272727
       }
   }
}
```

billingIncrement and owiFlagFall has integer type even though those fields are double type in the classes and database. I do not want to care about this but I causes error when I convert the return JSON to object again using Spring resttemplate. It does not cause any error if those field have double type like 30.0 and 0.0. This looks weird behaviour but it is true.
Can you give me any advice? Your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot explain exactly and do not know how I understand my case but suddenly it works. I did not do anything ~. What's this?

Comment: I that is the case please delete your question since no answer can be given.